# Overriding bundles versus overriding files

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-2.7

I'd like to ask what is the difference between overriding a bundle from the vendor and simply overriding its controllers or templates.

It seems to be the same to me, whether I override the bundle and then make my own files, or override the controllers and implement them with my own functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

Not all bundles will allow you to easily override /resources files. Some bundles expose those files in config, others may not do that. For those others, you would need to override the bundle.

Also, I think that you can override dependancy injection files when you override a bundle

Comment: Yeah I read that, that's where I'm coming from. I couldn't understand the difference, but if some don't let you, then it makes sense. Then is there any logic to not override the bundle every time?

Comment: Whenever you can do overrides via configuration, you should go that way. Bundle override is the last option